# Removing special character from Java String

Tags: java

I am trying to work around to remove symbols and special characters from a raw text in java and could not find way around. The text is taken from a free-text field in a website which may contain literally anything. I am taking this text from an external source and have no control to change setting. So I have to work around at my end. 
Some examples are

1) belem                           should be-->    belem

2) Ariana                          should be-->    Ariana

3) Harlem                          should be-->    Harlem

4)  Yz ️‍                          should be-->    Yz

5)  ここさけは7回は見に行くぞ      should be-->   ここさけは7回は見に行くぞ

6) دمي ازرق وطني ازرق    should be-->       دمي ازرق وطني ازرق

Any help please?

Comment: So by "special characters" you mean emoji? What have you tried?

Comment: You can try using regex. Example: `yourString.replaceAll("\\W", "")` to remove all non word characters. See [regex here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emoji value range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470079/emoji-value-range)

Comment: @TuyenNguyen This will also filter out all non English words

Answer (score 3):

You can try this regex that find all emojis in a string :

```
regex = "[\\ud83c\\udc00-\\ud83c\\udfff]|[\\ud83d\\udc00-\\ud83d\\udfff]|[\\u2600-\\u27ff]"
```

then remove all the emojis in it using `replaceAll()` method:

```
String text = "ここさけは7回は見に行くぞ ";
String regex = "[\\ud83c\\udc00-\\ud83c\\udfff]|[\\ud83d\\udc00-\\ud83d\\udfff]|[\\u2600-\\u27ff]";
System.out.println(text.replaceAll(regex, ""));
```

**Output**:

```
ここさけは7回は見に行くぞ
```

Comment: @user3212493 if you find the answer helpful mark it as solved to be reference in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "special characters" are surrogate pairs, try this.

```
static String removeSpecial(String s) {
    int[] r = s.codePoints()
        .filter(c -> c < Character.MIN_SURROGATE)
        .toArray();
    return new String(r, 0, r.length);
}
```

and

```
String[] testStrs = {
    "belem ",
    "Ariana ",
    "Harlem ",
    "Yz ️‍",
    "ここさけは7回は見に行くぞ",
    "دمي ازرق وطني ازرق "
};

for (String s : testStrs)
    System.out.println(removeSpecial(s));
```

results

```
belem 
Ariana 
Harlem 
Yz ‍
ここさけは7回は見に行くぞ
دمي ازرق وطني ازرق
```

Comment: Perfect and Thanks that's what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Use a character class for white space and the POSIX character class for "any letter or number from any language":

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\s\\p{Alnum}]", "");
```