# How to keep only emojis in string python

Tags: python, string, text, emoji

I'm working with twitter data and I've trying to count the number of occurrences of each emoji in a string. But, because emojis are showing as emojis in the string I'm struggling to find a way to filter them. In the following image you can see an example of one of the strings I'm working with:

[image]

Here I've got two flag emojis, one finger pointing right and one finger pointing left. My desired output would thus be just the four emojis in the string, something like:

```
 df['text_emoji']= df.text.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if emoji in i]
```

Do you know if there's some way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Emojiis have a really high ord() value for characters

Comment: @ChristianSloper that characteristic alone is [insufficient for identifying them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470079/emoji-value-range).